# Laravel, calling controller method from blade template file

Tags: php, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Heey guys! I use Laravel 5.4, WAMP for localhost. I am struggling with the problem to call a `Controller@methodName` within my `header.blade.php` file, because I want to show in my header.blade.php file all notifications for the User.  Normally I was getting all needed data with the help of routes in different pages. But for this case I need to call without using routes. Here is my code for my `NotificationController`:

```
class NotificationController extends Controller
{   
  public function getNotification(){
    $notifications = Notification::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $unread=0;

    foreach($notifications as $notify){
        if($notify->seen==0)$unread++;
    }

    return ['notifications'=>$notifications, 'unread'=>$unread];
  }
}
```

And I should receive all these data in my header file. I have used:  **{{App::make("NotificationController")->getNotification()}}**
and **{{NotificationController::getNotification() }}** But it says `Class NotificationController does not exist`. Please heelp!

Comment: why not make a route for that and hit that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling the controller method to get notifications, you can make a relationship method in your `User` model to retrieve all the notifications that belongs to the user and can use `Auth::user()->notifications`. For example:

```
// In User Model
public function notifications()
{
    // Import Notification Model at the top, i.e:
    // use App\Notification;
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class)
}
```

In your `view` you can now use something like this:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->notifications as $notification)
    // ...
@endforeach
```

Regarding your current problem, you need to use fully qualified namespace to make the controller instance, for example:

```
app(App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController::class)->getNotification()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full namespace:

For instance, `App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController::getNotification`

but of course, controllers aren't meant to be called the way you're using them. They're meant for routes. The better solution is to add a relationship in your user model like so:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class)
}
```

And then use this in your view like so:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
```

Comment: Yeap, exactly. Thank I did so )